# execution of isset before click the save button in php

Tags: php

I am having two php files, one contains a form and another to display the content entered and save button. After confirming the details are correct he has to save and the data should be inserted into the table. I have given the code below

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">     
 </script>  
 <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">      </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
 </head>
<body>
 <?php
   $roll=$_POST['roll'];
   $sname=$_POST['sname'];
   $fname=$_POST['fname'];
   $gender=$_POST['gender'];
   $aadhar=$_POST['aadhar'];
   $caste=$_POST['caste'];
 ?>
  <div class="container container-center">     
      <!-------------total panel------------------------------------>
      <div class="panel-info">
    <!------panel heading------>        
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h2><center><u>STUDENT DETAILS</u></center></h2>
    </div> <!-panel heading->      
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form method="post" action="">
        <table align="center" border="0">
           <tbody>              
             <tr>
               <td rowspan="7"><?php echo"<img src=/photo/$roll.jpg width='200px' height='300px' id='photo'>"; ?></td> 
               <td>1. Roll Number & Photo:</td>
               <td><?php echo"".strtoupper($roll).""; ?></td>                              
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>2. Name of the Student:</td>
               <td><?php echo"".strtoupper($sname).""; ?></td>             
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>3. Name of the Father:</td>
               <td><?php echo"".strtoupper($fname).""; ?></td>             
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>4. Gender:</td>
               <td><?php 
                    if($gender=='M')
                    { echo"Male";}                        
                    else
                    {echo"Female";} 
                   ?></td>             
             </tr>
              <tr>
               <td>5. Aadhar Number:</td>
               <td><?php echo"$aadhar"; ?></td>            
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>6. Caste:</td>
               <td><?php echo"$caste"; ?></td>             
             </tr>
              <tr>                 
               <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="save"></td>               
             </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>                
       </form>    
    </div>      
   </div>  
</div>
 <?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    echo"<script>alert('success')</script>";
 }
?>
</body>
```

when i click the save button then only the data must be saved. but even if not click the save the php code in isset is executing.
the data obtained by $_POST is from the form.

Please help me.

Comment: @PraveenKumar English please

Comment: @PAvan Bhai.... actually problem is that,, you dont get the data on this page ... in your `POST` request with given variable so that Please Just Check it . Other Code Is Fine. !! :) PAVAN BHAI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with your code, such as:

- There's no point having a form and *save* button(in *another* page) if you don't have *input* elements and don't send your data using `$_POST` superglobal. Create *input* elements for each of your fields with `type="hidden"`, for example like this:

  ```
  <td><?php echo strtoupper($roll); ?><input type="hidden" name="roll" value="<?php echo strtoupper($roll); ?>"></td>
  ```

  Here's the full form code,

  ```
  // your code
  <form method="post" action="">
      <table align="center" border="0">
          <tbody>              
          <tr>
              <td rowspan="7"><?php echo"<img src=/photo/$roll.jpg width='200px' height='300px' id='photo'>"; ?></td> 
              <td>1. Roll Number & Photo:</td>
              <td><?php echo strtoupper($roll); ?><input type="hidden" name="roll" value="<?php echo strtoupper($roll); ?>"></td>                              
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>2. Name of the Student:</td>
              <td><?php echo strtoupper($sname); ?><input type="hidden" name="sname" value="<?php echo strtoupper($sname); ?>"></td>             
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>3. Name of the Father:</td>
              <td><?php echo strtoupper($fname); ?><input type="hidden" name="fname" value="<?php echo strtoupper($fname); ?>"></td>             
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>4. Gender:</td>
              <td>
              <?php 
                  if($gender=='M'){ 
                      echo"Male";
                  }else{
                      echo"Female";
                  } 
              ?>
              <input type="hidden" name="gender" value="<?php echo $gender; ?>">
              </td>             
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>5. Aadhar Number:</td>
              <td><?php echo $aadhar; ?><input type="hidden" name="aadhar" value="<?php echo $aadhar; ?>"></td>            
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>6. Caste:</td>
              <td><?php echo $caste; ?><input type="hidden" name="caste" value="<?php echo $caste; ?>"></td>             
          </tr>
          <tr>                 
              <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="save"></td>               
          </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>                
  </form>  
  // your code
  ```
- I don't see any code where you're inserting the form data into the table, you should have a code block like this in *another* page(where you have displayed the form data and has the *save* button):

  ```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $roll = $_POST['roll'];
      $sname = $_POST['sname'];
      $fname = $_POST['fname'];
      $gender = $_POST['gender'];
      $aadhar = $_POST['aadhar'];
      $caste = $_POST['caste'];

      // your INSERT operation
  }
  ```

Comment: without click the save button the code in isset is executing

Comment: @PAVAN That's because `$_POST['submit']` is already set in the very first page(NOT in *another* page), use a different `name` for submit button there.

Answer (score 1):

> **NOTE:**

### Actually Problem is that, you don't get the data on this page.. in your `POST` request with given variable so that Please Just Check it . Other Code Is Fine. !! ( `Here I am Just Pass Dummy Data` ) Like Below.

---

```
   $roll= '1234';
   $sname='XYZ';
   $fname= 'ABC';
   $gender= 'M';
   $aadhar= '123456789100';
   $caste= 'A12345';
```

---

> **Solution:** You Have To `Get DATA Here` in `post` request from your `first_php_page` form where user enter the details regarding given fields: `roll,sname,fname,gender,aadhar,caste`

---

> After here in `secound_php_page` check that `Submit` button is set then store the values in `varable` Like `below Code:`
>
> ### NOTE: At The End YoU Have To Write The `Insert` Query On Save Button Click. To Store The data in Database.

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
   $roll=$_POST['roll'];
   $sname=$_POST['sname'];
   $fname=$_POST['fname'];
   $gender=$_POST['gender'];
   $aadhar=$_POST['aadhar'];
   $caste=$_POST['caste'];
 }
?>
```

---

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">     
 </script>  
 <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">      </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
 </head>
<body>

   <?php
   /*
   $roll=$_POST['roll'];
   $sname=$_POST['sname'];
   $fname=$_POST['fname'];
   $gender=$_POST['gender'];
   $aadhar=$_POST['aadhar'];
   $caste=$_POST['caste'];
   */

   // SET THE DUMMY DATA FOR Result check

   $roll= '1234';
   $sname='XYZ';
   $fname= 'ABC';
   $gender= 'M';
   $aadhar= '123456789100';
   $caste= 'A12345';


   ?>

  <div class="container container-center">     
      <!-- total panel -->
      <div class="panel-info">
    <!-- panel heading -->        
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h2><center><u>STUDENT DETAILS</u></center></h2>
    </div> 
    <!--panel heading -->      
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form method="post" action="">
        <table align="center" border="0">
           <tbody>              
             <tr>
               <td rowspan="7"><?php echo"<img src=/photo/$roll.jpg width='200px' height='300px' id='photo'>"; ?></td> 
               <td>1. Roll Number & Photo:</td>
               <td><?php echo"".strtoupper($roll).""; ?></td>                              
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>2. Name of the Student:</td>
               <td><?php echo"".strtoupper($sname).""; ?></td>             
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>3. Name of the Father:</td>
               <td><?php echo"".strtoupper($fname).""; ?></td>             
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>4. Gender:</td>
               <td><?php 
                    if($gender=='M')
                    { echo"Male";}                        
                    else
                    {echo"Female";} 
                   ?></td>             
             </tr>
              <tr>
               <td>5. Aadhar Number:</td>
               <td><?php echo"$aadhar"; ?></td>            
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td>6. Caste:</td>
               <td><?php echo"$caste"; ?></td>             
             </tr>
              <tr>                 
               <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="save"></td>               
             </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>                
       </form>    
    </div>      
   </div>  
</div>
 <?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    echo"<script>alert('success')</script>";
 }
?>
</body>
</HTML>
```

> **OUTPUT:** DATA Display

[image]

> **AND** ONCLICK SAVE

[image]